# error expected primary-expression before 'char'

Tags: c, compiler-construction

i have a question,
i am trying this

```
if (strncmp(m_DSServer, "TCP:", 4) != 0 )
    return DS_AS_PROCESS_NAME_INCORRECT;
if
    if(strchr(char *(m_DSServer[4]),':')== NULL) //here it is giving me primary-expression before 'char
        return DS_AS_PROCESS_NAME_INCORRECT;
else
    if(strchr(m_DSServer[4],'/')== NULL)
        return DS_AS_PROCESS_NAME_INCORRECT;
```

Comment: I suspect you need parenthesis around the char* cast.  Like (char*).  However, posting a bit more code may help.  Also, is the if actually duplicated, or a typo?

Comment: I tried to format this code, but gave up. I couldn't understand what is code, and what is text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start searching from the 5. character, do

```
 strchr(&m_DSServer[4],':')
```

Comment: thanks nos,this is what i was asking

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, cast syntax that has the `type(value)` form is a chiefly C++ syntax. It is not supported in C. And your question is tagged [C], not [C++]. In C language you have to use the `(type) value` syntax when you want to perform a cast.

Secondly, even in C++ the `type(value)` cast syntax requires the `type` part to consist of a "compact" type specifier, i.e. even in C++ you can't use `char *` in this context.

Thirdly, regardless of the syntax you use, it is entirely not clear what you are trying to do by casting `m_DSServer[4]` value (which is apparently a `char`) to pointer type. This just does not make any sense.

If you wanted to do a search for a `:` character starting from the 4th position in string `m_DSServer`, you should do something like `strchr(&m_DSServer[4], ':')`. No casts necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strchr(char *(m_DSServer[4]),':') == NULL)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`char *(m_DSServer[4])` is nonsense. My guess is that you want to search the string for `:`, starting from the 4th character. In that case, you want a pointer to the 4th character:

```
if (strchr(m_DSServer+4,':') == NULL)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```